# VBA search in two ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I'm more than new at this, and I'm having trouble sorting out For...Next loops.

I want to track to two text variables in two columns, so that when both variables are found in a row text is added to that row in a different column.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub AB()
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Set Rng1 = Range("B1:B100")
Set Rng2 = Range("A1:A100")
For Each cel In Rng1
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "A") > 0 Then
    For Each cel In Rng2
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "B") > 0 Then
            cel.Offset(0, 5).Value = "AB"
        End If
    Next
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Move the inner loop outside the first `if` and combine the if statements like `If InStr(1, cel.Value, "A") > 0 and If InStr(1, cel.Value, "B") > 0 then` Edit: you'd need to declare a `cel2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might even be able to just do this?

```
Sub AB()

With ActiveSheet

For I = 1 To 100

    If InStr(1, .Cells(I, 2), "A") > 0 And InStr(1, .Cells(I, 1), "B") > 0 Then
        .Cells(I, 6).Value = "AB" 'i think offset 5 is column F?
    End If

Next

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate you have an answer now, but here's a different method using Find. Always good to know several ways to do something.

```
Sub AB()

Dim rng As Range
Dim itemaddress As String

With Columns(1)

Set rng = .Find("A", searchorder:=xlByRows, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then

        itemaddress = rng.Address

        Do
            If rng.Offset(0, 1) = "B" Then
                rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = "AB"
            End If

        Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
        Loop While Not rng Is Nothing And itemaddress <> rng.Address

    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `cel' to step through each loop - the inner loop will get confused.

Along the vein of @findwindow answer (appeared as I was typing this).  Loop just once and when a match is found check the cell next to it.

```
Sub AB()

    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim cel1 As Range

    'Be specific about which sheet your ranges are on.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Rng1 = .Range("B1:B100")
        Set Rng2 = .Range("A1:A100")
    End With

    For Each cel1 In Rng1
        'Check each value in column B.
        If InStr(1, cel1.Value, "A") > 0 Then
            'If a match is found, check the value next to it.
            If InStr(1, cel1.Offset(, -1), "B") > 0 Then
                cel1.Offset(, 4).Value = "AB"
            End If
        End If
    Next cel1

End Sub
```